# Is there a nice way to find the trigger method of an ActiveRecored validation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord

I have a model that has multiple validations. I want to skip one validation only if it was triggered (in my case, by saving) from a certain method.

To clarify, I don't want to skip the rest of validations.

I can inspect the call stack by the caller array, but I wonder if it can be done in a nicer way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#using-a-symbol-with-if-and-unless) is what you're looking for. Here is an example:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :skip_validation

  validates :my_validation, unless: :skip_validation
  validates :another_validation
end
```

Then, wherever you want to skip `my_validation` just set `skip_validation` to `true` on your object before you call `save`.

```
m = Model.new
m.skip_validation = true
m.save # my_validation will not run, and another_validation will run
```